# Something like object rest in Typescript? similar to Partial<T>

Tags: typescript

Here's an simple example code:

```
interface Params {
  a: string
  b: number
  c: boolean
}

const f1 = (p1: Params) => void;

const f2 = (p2: Params2) => f1({a: 'default', ...p2});
```

`f2` fills `Params.a` with a default value. Therefore, `Params2` is `Params` with `a?: string` (`a` being optional).

How to create this `Params2` without manually listing `a`, `b`, `c`?

I've tried the following, but it does not work:

```
interface Params2 extends Params {
  a?: string
}
```

Using `Partial<T>` is no good since it make all properties optional instead of making just `a` optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) (specifically [`Exclude`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#predefined-conditional-types)) and [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) (specifically `Pick` and `Partial`), you can express the idea of taking an existing type and selectively turning some of its properties into optional properties:

```
type Optionalize<T, K extends keyof T> = 
  Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>
```

That basically says that `Optionalize<T, K>` is what you get when you take out the properties with keys in `K` and make them optional, and leave all the rest of the properties as-is.

```
interface Params2 extends Optionalize<Params, 'a'> {}
```

You can verify that `Params2` is equivalent to

```
{a?: string, b: number, c: boolean}
```

as desired.

---

A different idea: your `Params` is actually narrower than `Params2` so while you can't get `Params2` by extending `Params`, you *can* do the reverse:

```
interface Params2 {
  a?: string
  b: number
  c: boolean
}
interface Params extends Params2 {
  a: string
}
```

This may or may not work for you, but it might be more straightforward than doing the `Optionalize` type-juggling above.

---

Hope that helps; good luck!